# SIMPLE: sort Booklist on Web into Excel using VBA macro?

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

Here is a website with a list of books in a relatively simple format.

http://www.autism-resources.com/autism.bib
I copied the list into excel, and each group of % symbols is a listing for a book, with different details like keywords and such. for instance %T = titles.
I want to create a macro to search through the list and copy every row that starts with "% whatever marker i choose" to the B column

Here is code I found and changed to do pretty close to what I want, except I keep getting an error.

```
Sub SearchForString()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim celltxt As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

LSearchRow = 1

LCopyToRow = 1

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value

    If InStr(1, celltxt, "%T") > 0 Then

        Cells("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Cells("B" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveCell.Paste

        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Also, I believe the:

```
While Len(range....) > 0
```

is set to keep looping until the active cell is empty, but the data is separated by a blank row for each book. I can go through and delete the empty rows, but is there a way to get around that with code?

Comment: What about cases where there are multiple instances of a particular tag for a given book ?  Eg - more than one %A tag ?

Comment: they could just be put in the same row, one column over?

Comment: If you do that, then your columns won't line up, unless you were to first go through the entire list to find the maximum number of "author" columns required.  How about just putting the content in the same cell, but separated by a newline character?

Comment: For now, Id just like to copy over "%B" because that has the isbn's and I can search for the rest of the book details using the isbn. but in the code above, Im copying "%T"

Comment: Cells() requires one or two numeric arguments: eg. Cells(2) or Cells(2,4).  It's looking for either a numeric index ("second cell on the sheet") or a row&column pair (row2, col4).  So something like **Cells(LSearchRow,1).Copy Destination:=Cells(LCopyToRow,2)** would work.  Note you don't need to select cells to copy or paste: you can do it in one line. Also, your loop seems like it would stop the minute it hit a blank row in between books, unless you already filtered those out.  Last: better to Dim any Row/Column counters as Long (just in case you end up with more data than planned...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.  I used a Web Query and downloaded the data to A1 on sheet "Raw"

```
'simple struct to describe each line of data
Public Type InfoLine
    Tag As String
    Data As String
End Type

Sub Tester()

    Dim rw As Range, src As Range
    Dim dest As Range
    Dim line As String
    Dim numBlank As Integer
    Dim HadContent As Boolean
    Dim info As InfoLine

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw").Range("A1")
    Set rw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Books").Rows(1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    numBlank = 0
    'stop after 10 consecutive blank cells
    Do While numBlank < 10
        line = Trim(src.Value)

        If Len(line) > 0 Then

            numBlank = 0
            info = GetInfoLine(line)

            If info.Tag <> "" Then

                Set dest = Nothing
                Select Case info.Tag
                    Case "T": Set dest = rw.Cells(1)
                    Case "B": Set dest = rw.Cells(2)
                    Case "A": Set dest = rw.Cells(3)
                End Select

                If Not dest Is Nothing Then
                    HadContent = True
                    'does the cell already have content?
                    If Len(dest.Value) > 0 Then
                        'add new line after line break
                        dest.Value = dest.Value & Chr(10) & info.Data
                    Else
                        dest.Value = info.Data
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                'no tag - continues previous line (if captured)
                If Not dest Is Nothing Then
                    dest.Value = dest.Value & " " & line
                End If
            End If
        Else
            numBlank = numBlank + 1
            If numBlank = 1 And HadContent Then Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
            HadContent = False
        End If

        Set src = src.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function GetInfoLine(line As String) As InfoLine
    Dim rv As InfoLine
    If line Like "%*" Then
        rv.Tag = UCase(Trim(Mid(line, 2, InStr(1, line, " ", 0) - 2)))
        rv.Data = Trim(Mid(line, InStr(line, " ")))
    Else
        rv.Tag = ""
        rv.Data = line
    End If
    GetInfoLine = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, and Ray. This worked great, except the newline character confused me for a minute. I just found and replaced them all with commas. Could you humor me and critique the short code I wrote? It was my first try and any comments would help me improve.  Basically I was trying to have the macro loop and search within each cell for a "%*" marker and then copy that cell over to the next column. I could  then sub in a different marker and use the next column over and repeat. But it never worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my comment on your question for suggestions on your posted code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have trouble finding someone on SO that will write the code for you.

But, if you're looking for a starting points, I'd say the first thing that comes to mind is using a webquery to import the data into your workbook.

Webquery's go all the way back to Excel '97, but here's the button in Excel 2010 to get you started:
[image]

That will import your data into a worksheet.

Then it would be a simple loop to determine if the line starts with % and parse the text accordingly till you reach the next cell that starts with %.

Loops can be researched within the help file and there are many articles on SO and the web that should give you some good ideas.

Start with that, write some code and then post what you write if you still have issues.